# Blueprint unloads all c++ components upon restart

Tags: compilation, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

Whenever I close and reopen the Unreal Engine 5 Editor, any blueprints on which I added C++ components removes the C++ components entirely. I reference many variables in the BP from that C++ component and when that happens I needa relink everything.[image: This is what I see]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ion know why this happens, but starting the project from Visual Studio stops this from happening. Just a quick fix I found, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was creating a plugin and by default the `LoadingPhase` in the `.uplugin` file was set to `Default`.

Once I changed it to `PreLoadingScreen`, the C++ components I added to my blueprint compiled OK after restarting the editor.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to compile the project from VS Code instead of using the Live Coding compiler from UE5.

In short, in VS Code with UE5 closed, with the project opened, hit Ctrl+Shift+B and select "*ProjectName*Editor Win64 Development Build" and just wait for it to finish.

Source: Udemy's course "Unreal Engine 5 C++ Developer: Learn C++ & Make Video Games"

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times you need to recompile using VS code with ue5 not running and when that doesn’t work you go into the project folder and delete intermediate and binaries, right click the project file and select regenerate project files ( you might need to “show more” in windows 11 to get that option) then reload the project from the .uproject file and everything should save properly afterward

Answer (score 0):

Go to the editor preferences and search for the force compile on startup turn it on it will auto compile the whole project and the attachments will be there where they should be and all the classes also will be there it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).